# Class 'app\assets\AppAsset' not found in Yii2, file exist in assets

Tags: yii2

I was given the task to put the application on YII, i.e. I got its code and I have to put it on the server. Unfortunately, I have a problem, I threw the application on the server, I started the composer, I changed the data to the base, and after entering the website I get the following message:

```
Class 'app\assets\AppAsset' not found
```

I checked this and in the assets directory is the AppAsset class which has the code:

```
<?Php
namespace app\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
     public $basePath = '@webroot';
     public $baseUrl = '@web';
     public $css = [
          'Css/app.css'
     ];

     public $js = [
         'Js/app.js'
     ];

     public $depends = [
         'Yii\web\YiiAsset'
         'Yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset'
     ];
}
?>
```

I am looking for a solution to this problem all the time, but nothing works.

Comment: `<? Php` is it like this on your file as well? Or just a typo when you did the copy/past

Comment: The error occurred when copying the code i fix it

Comment: When a class is not found, it's most of the time a typo (notice Unix systems are case sensitive). It can also be the folder that as a different typo than the namespace (excepting `app` that is generally mapped with PSR)

Comment: Also, as speaking of case sensitive, it's `<?php` not `<?Php`

Comment: I solved the problem, I had to create the assets directory in the main application directory, not the web. Now I have a problem with the database, i.e. after launching the application, it does not create any structure in the database and only shows that there is no table and that's all.

Comment: Did you run `yii migrate`?

Comment: yes, but i get information "migration not found"